# Video call functionality for iOS devices

Tags: ios, iphone, p2p, videochat, video-conferencing

I want to implement an application which needs to have a P2P video chat functionality. The first requirement is to be able make a call even if the app is not active on the iPhone which is being called. As i know this kind of call can be made by using VoIP protocols but can i create a video conference according to the answer of a this kind of call?

The second functionality is of course creating the video conference itself. There are paid services for this but is there any other way to create a video chat? I thought it may be implemented with RTC but RTC is not supported by UIWebViews. So is there anyway to create a video chat on iOS devices with or withour RTC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a voip stack to make voip calls. If the VoIP stack lib supports video transmission then you are good to go. take a look at PJSIP.

Comment: Video isn't *technically* supported in PJSIP on iOS.  Supposedly this guy has video working with pjsip in iOS, so it'll be a good starting point: https://code.google.com/p/siphon/wiki/VIdeoSupport

Comment: thanks Matt for further clarification. i didnt want to take away the joy of finding out that its pain in the neck ;-)

Comment: As i made a research, video is supported in PJSIP v2.x on iOS. But thanks for the info..